# The use of the future continuous in place of the future simple

Tags: future-tense, future-continuous

Tell me please why the presenter in this [clip](https://youtu.be/Ad2MtgOL2u4) decided to use the future progressive instead of the future simple. It is at 1 minute and 56 seconds. Here is the exerpt:

> If you don't like my cooking, **I will not be inviting** you to my dinner party.

How is this sentence different in meaning than the following one?

> If you don't like my cooking, **I will not invite** you to my dinner party.

Answer (score 1):

The denotation is the same, but the future progressive sounds more natural to me.

Comment: Could you exolpain why it sounds more natural to you?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Maybe because the simple tense sounds like a flat declaration, ending the conversation, while the progressive sounds more like banter, as if the speaker is negotiating.